compact projective objects in Animae
This is well-known but I can't find a reference: Define the infinity category of Animae as the coherent nerve of Kan complexes. Why finite unions of points are the only compact, projective objects in Animae? For me $X$ is compact and projective means that $Hom(X,-)$ commutes with filtered colimits and colimits of shape $\Delta^{op}$.

I don't think you need a reference for this, as the proof is rather short. Given a simplicial set $K\colon\Delta^\mathrm{op}
\to\mathrm{Set}$ we know that the underlying anima $|K|$ is given by the colimit $\mathrm{colim}(\Delta^\mathrm{op}\xrightarrow{K}\mathrm{Set}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{An})$. For a set $S$, the simplicial set $K^S\cong\prod_{s\in S} K$ has $n$-simplices $(K^S)_n\cong (K_n)^S$.
If $X$ is a projective anima, we have a map $X\to\pi_0(X)$ that we will show to be an equivalence. It suffices to show that, for any anima $Y$, the map
$$
\mathrm{An}(\pi_0(X),Y)\to\mathrm{An}(X,Y)
$$
is an equivalence. It suffices to prove so for $Y=|K|$ for an arbitrary Kan complex $K$. In this case, we can see that the above map is homotopic to the composite of equivalences
$$
\mathrm{An}(\pi_0(X),|K|)\simeq|K|^{\pi_0(X)}\simeq|K^{\pi_0(S)}|\simeq\mathrm{colim}_{\Delta^\mathrm{op}}(K_n)^{\pi_0(X)}\simeq\mathrm{colim}_{\Delta^\mathrm{op}}\mathrm{Set}(\pi_0(X),K_n)\simeq
\mathrm{colim}_{\Delta^\mathrm{op}}\mathrm
{An}(X,K_n)\simeq
\mathrm{An}(X,|K|),$$
where we have used that $K$ is a Kan complex when we concluded that $|K^{\pi_0(X)}|\simeq|K|^{\pi_0(X)}$.
If $X$ is additionally compact then $\pi_0(X)$ is finite by the same argument why a compact object in $\mathrm{Set}$ is finite, so a compact projective anima $X$ must satisfy that $X\simeq\pi_0(X)$ is a finite set. It is not hard to see that any such finite set is also a compact projective anima.

$|K|^{π_0(X)}≃|K^{π_0(S)}|$ fails for some $K$ if $π_0(S)$ is infinite.  It does hold, for example, if $K$ is a Kan complex.

Good catch, I forgot to add that assumption.
